# How to get radio button selected value from dynamically generated radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I am generating radiobuttons dynamically using ng-repeat as below.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="level in permissions">
        <input name="level.perm_levelname" type="radio" ng-model="level.perm_levelname" value="{{level.perm_levelname}}"> {{level.perm_levelname}}
        <a ng-click="gotopermMap({permisssionID: level.id})">View</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="APPLY" ng-click="apply()" />
```

I am trying to get selected radio button as below.

```
 $scope.apply=function()
        {
            var permname = $scope.name;
            console.log($scope.level.perm_levelname);
        }
```

I am getting error  Cannot read property 'perm_levelname' of undefined. May i get help here to get selected radio button? Thank you

Comment: when do you call $scope.apply() ?

Comment: whats the value in $scope.level?

Comment: group the radio button by name `<input name="myradiobtn"`

Comment: I have button like    <input type="button" value="APPLY" ng-click="apply()"/>

Comment: why you call on button click ? if user do not select any radio button then its will be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group radio buttons by a name and specify a common scope variable for radio buttons `ng-modal`

```
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="level in permissions">
       <input name="myradiobtn" type="radio" ng-model="myradioBtnValue" ng-value="level.perm_levelname">
       {{level.perm_levelname}}
       <a ng-click="gotopermMap({permisssionID: level.id})">View</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <input type="button" value="APPLY" ng-click="apply()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting undefined.

Comment: where you getting undefined?

Comment: console.log($scope.myradioBtnValue);

Comment: use `ng-value` for `value` in radio button

Comment: Thank you. Still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148371/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-azad).

Answer (score 1):

> Use `ng-click` event for radio button to get current selected value and assign the value a scope object. then get the value from saved scope abject while you click apply button.

DEMO:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

$scope.permissions= [{perm_levelname:"hai"},{perm_levelname:"bye"},{perm_levelname:"come"},{perm_levelname:"go"}]
      $scope.apply=function()
        {   
        alert($scope.currecntClickValue);
        }
         $scope.currecntClick=function(currecntClickValue)
         {                                                     
          $scope.currecntClickValue=currecntClickValue.perm_levelname;
         }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="level in permissions">       
       <input name="groupName" type="radio" ng-click="currecntClick(level)" ng-value="level.perm_levelname">
       {{level.perm_levelname}}
       <a href="#" ng-click="gotopermMap({permisssionID: level.id})">View</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <input type="button" value="APPLY" ng-click="apply()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use radio button group like this--

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="level in permissions">
       <input name="btnGroup" type="radio" ng-model="radioButtonValue" value="{{level.perm_levelname}}">
       {{level.perm_levelname}}
       <a ng-click="gotopermMap({permisssionID: level.id})">View</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <input type="button" value="APPLY" ng-click="apply()"/>
```

And inside of Controller-

```
$scope.radioButtonValue='';

 $scope.apply=function()
        {
            var permname = $scope.name;
            console.log($scope.radioButtonValue);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting undefined.

Comment: Now i am getting blank.